# background TCP/IP connection in Javafx

Tags: multithreading, javafx, tcp

I am trying to make a game with a multiplayer option in javafx using TCP/IP connection. I created a thread that handles the connections in the background so that it will listen to connections while the user plays offline. If someone tries to connect i want the thread fire a button on the main javafx application. The problem is i can't modify a UI on another thread. I tried using `Task<>`, `platform.runlater`, and `Timeline` to no effect.

```
  Thread thread = new Thread(){
       public void run(){

            try {

                int ServerPort=6779;

                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ServerPort);
                System.out.println("waiting for player to join");
                Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ObjectOutputStream outToServer1 = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("connected");
                Board boardJ = new BoardM();
                outToServer1.writeObject(boardJ);

                boardS=boardJ;
                ServerBoard.fire();



             } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }

       }
   };
  thread.start();
```

Comment: Platform.runLater is probably the way to go here but why don't you show your attempts here?

Comment: The code is pretty much the same. I just changed the thread to Platform.runLater with other minor necessary changes of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thread is ok here. What you have to do is to wrap the fireing of the button in a Platform.runLater call.